# Argument does not begin with '--' error while executing Apache Beam WordCount example from Eclipse in java

Tags: eclipse, apache-beam

I'm trying to execute the example WordCount(Java code) from Eclipse as specified in 
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-eclipse#run-the-wordcount-example-pipeline-on-the-cloud-dataflow-service

While executing through RunConfiguration, getting below error in Eclipse console.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument '-output=gs://bucket-for-beam/stage-folder/output-file-prefix' does not begin with '--'
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_sdks_java_core.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:191)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.option[s.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseCommandLine(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1423)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.access$200(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.as(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:294)
    at com.gcp.dataflow.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:190)][1]
```

I've created a bucket, named 'bucket-for-beam' folder,named 'stage-folder':

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`-` and `--` are different. You have specified the first one on the arguments tab. It expects the second one.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to a space in between the different option of the commands

Comment: He only has one option and zero spaces